# Maxima $|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|$ when $|z| = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was solving this problem 5 from book namely Complex Analysis A to Z , here we have to find range of
$$ y=|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|$$ with $|z|=1$ .

[image]

First of all i didn't get the step
$|1-z+z^2|=\sqrt{|7-2t^2|}$  .

Then i tried to solve this question by substituting $z= \cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

After simplification and plotting the graph i got
$$y=|t|+\sqrt{t+3}$$ where $ t=2\cos\theta-1$ and $$\sqrt3\leq y\leq {13\over4}$$ .

So i actually got complex numbers $z=-{7\over8}\pm \frac{\sqrt15}{8}$  which gives $y={13\over4} > 3\sqrt{{7\over 6}}$ maxima we needed to prove .

So which answer is right did i make a mistake ?

> There's a similar question asked so just confirm me if book is wrong and question can be merged with that ?

> Also the step i mentioned earlier how author got that ?

Comment: Your calculation is correct (both the minimum and the maximum)

Comment: So book's answer is wrong ? And the step $|1-z+z^2|=\sqrt{|7-2t^2|}$in picture of book , how author got it ?

Comment: Please, see my answer

Comment: Are you working from the 2005 edition?  I have the 2014 edition of _Complex Numbers... A to Z_ by  Andreescu and Andrica.  Problems 5 and 6 on pages 13 and 14 are the same, _except_ that the inequality is shown (and solved) as $$ \sqrt3 \ \le \ |1 + z| \ + \ |1 - z + z^2| \ \le \ \frac{13}{4} \ \ . $$  The solution there is substantially similiar to what **lcv** shows (there are also a revised graph of the function), so it looks like you caught an error that was subsequently corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The mistake in the book comes from the fact that one has

\begin{align}
\vert 1- z + z^2 \vert^2 &= 3-2z^* - 2z +z^2 +(z^*)^2 \\
& = (1 - z^* -z)^2, 
\end{align}

with $z^*$ denoting complex conjugate of $z$. Hence, using the notation of the book,

$$
\vert 1- z + z^2 \vert = \vert 3 - t^2 \vert \ . 
$$

Indeed $f(t) = t + \vert 3 - t^2 \vert$ satisfies

$$
\sqrt{3}\le f(t) \le \frac{13}{4}
$$

when $t\in[0,2]$. I have no idea where the mistake may have originated. It also seems that this way of thought is not the simplest either.

Comment: $|1-z+z^2|^2$=...

Comment: @Aqua yes of course, thanks fixed